# Will infinite while loop inside fork-join_any end after exiting?

Tags: system-verilog

Will the first `while` loop continue after I have exited `fork/join_any`? I see the message "iam here" after the message "after join any".

I expect that the first `while` loop will stop when I exit `fork/join_any`.
Is that not the case?

```
fork
    begin
        while(1)
            begin
                @(posedge trigger_clock);
                do something
                $info("i am here");
                
            end
    end
    begin 
        while(1)
            begin 
                @(posedge trigger_clock);
                if(condition is true)
                    begin
                        break;
                    end
            end
    end 
join_any
$info("after join any");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed, the top `while` loop continues to execute even when you exit the `fork` when the bottom `while` loop completes.  This is expected.

If you want the top `while` loop to stop executing when you exit the `fork`, you can use the `disable fork` statement:

```
fork
    // ...
join_any
disable fork;
$info("after join any");
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.6 *Process control*.